# Cheapest set containing electric motor

Tags: building, piece-information, sets, bricks-and-pieces

Which LEGO set is the cheapest I can buy in a store with an electric motor in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: LEGO prices fluctuate depending on retailer (LEGO.com, Wal-Mart, Target, Toys'R'Us, etc.), so "cheapest" also depends on the time of year and the retailer you look at.

Secondly, are you only interested in a PowerFunctions motor, and is the set you ask for just a vehicle to get the motor? In that case you might want to know that you can just buy [a single motor from LEGO Shop@Home](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-M-Motor-8883). Current price (Dec15) is $7.99 plus tax plus shipping.

[image]

You can also buy a kit with motor, lights, batterybox and a few gears directly from LEGO [here](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Motor-Set-8293); this set costs currently $29.99.

[image]

Power Functions motors typically come in the higher-priced Technic sets, of which currently [42008 Service Truck](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Service-Truck-42008) is the cheapest at $103.98 sale price.

[image]

There are a few non-Technic models every now and then that have Power Functions motors in them but I do not know of any set currently available that has a motor included.